# Use SSH tunnel to test apps with on-premise destination locally

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I would like to run my app locally and use the on-premise system connected via Cloud Connector (connectivity) and destination service. I was already pointed to the [documentation](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/js/features/connectivity/on-premise#connectivity-service) but it is not working as expected. Is there a more detailed step-by-step tutorial available for the setup?

I followed the [documentation](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/js/features/connectivity/on-premise#connectivity-service) and expected to be able to run my app using

```
cds watch
```

but it looks like the app is still trying to call the destination from my local client instead of using the ssh tunnel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry we don't have a more detailed step by step guide, but I think it makes sense to extend the documentation.

Form the cds watch I guess you are using a CAP application. This should in principle be possible, but in order to minimize the sources of errors I would do the following:

- open the ssh tunnel
- just execute a node my-test.js
- add a copy of your VCAP_SERVICE variables to the process (dotenv lib)
- Remember to adjust port/host proxy in your VCAP_SERVICE to point to the local side of your tunnel
- in the "my-test.js" call getDestination() from the SDK and have a look (if you do not provide a user JWT here you have to use a basic auth destination)
- The destination should have a proxy config containing the local side and all necessary auth headers
- Execute a call using this destination. The request should use the proxy located in CF via the ssh tunnel

I made a E2E test in the context of an other project and this snippet worked for me:

```
//cf enable-ssh My-App
//cf ssh MyApp -L 4711:connectivityproxy.cf.sap.hana.ondemand.com:20003
const destination = await getDestination('MyDestination',{})


    destination.proxyConfiguration = {
        host:'localhost',
        port:4711,
        headers:destination.proxyConfiguration.headers,
        protocol:destination.proxyConfiguration.protocol
    }

    const bps = await BusinessPartner.requestBuilder().getAll().top(3).execute(destination)
```

Best
Frank

Comment: I made a E2E test in the context of an other project and this snippet worked for me: